# Why is EvaluateScriptAsync returning an empty expando object in CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am trying to write an application in C# using CefSharp. My intention is to fetch all the links on the given page eg,

```
https://wixlabs---dropbox-folder.appspot.com/index?instance=lp5CbqBbK6JUFzCW2hXENEgT4Jn0Q-U1-lIAgEbjeio.eyJpbnN0YW5jZUlkIjoiYjNiNzk5YjktNjE5MS00ZDM0LTg3ZGQtYjY2MzI1NWEwMDNhIiwiYXBwRGVmSWQiOiIxNDkyNDg2NC01NmQ1LWI5NGItMDYwZi1jZDU3YmQxNmNjMjYiLCJzaWduRGF0ZSI6IjIwMTgtMDEtMjJUMTg6Mzk6MjkuNjAwWiIsInVpZCI6bnVsbCwidmVuZG9yUHJvZHVjdElkIjpudWxsLCJkZW1vTW9kZSI6ZmFsc2V9&target=_top&width=728&compId=comp-j6bjhny1&viewMode=viewer-seo
```

When I load the page and open the dev tools and execute

`document.getElementsByTagName('a');`

in the dev tools I get 374 results. Next I execute the following code from BrowserLoadingStateChanged:-

```
private async Task ProcessLinksAsync()
        {
            var frame = browser.GetMainFrame();
            var response = await frame.EvaluateScriptAsync("(function() { return document.getElementsByTagName('a'); })();", null);
            ExpandoObject result = response.Result as ExpandoObject;

            Console.WriteLine("Result:" + result);//What do I do here?
        }
```

I get an expando object which seems to contain nothing. I am saying this because I used a break point and inspected the object. I have gone through https://keyholesoftware.com/2019/02/11/create-your-own-web-bots-in-net-with-cefsharp/ , https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#javascript-integration and the questions on SO but was unable to solve my problem.
Am I doing something wrong here?
My actual intention is to fetch the links and then navigate to them.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I used the following script in browser and dev tools both return 187 results which is correct.

```
(function() { 
    var links=document.getElementsByClassName('file-link'); 
    var linksArray = new Array(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
        linksArray[i] = String(links[i].href); 
    } 
    return linksArray; 
})();
```

But in my application I get a 0 length array.

EDIT-2:
I used the following code to get the DOM:-

```
public void OnContextCreated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame)
        {
            ContextCreated?.Invoke(this, frame);
            const string script = "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ alert(document.links.length); });";

            frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(script);
        }
```

For every other site I tried the code was successful except the URL mentioned above. Could any one possibly tell me what could be possibly wrong as the DOM is loaded in the dev tools and fully accessible. So, I guess something might be missing in my code.
Thanks again.

Comment: What is the return type of getElementsByTagName? Is the type an array? I ask this knowing the answer to both, I think it's important you research the answers if you don't already know.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. I am basically a Desktop Developer not well versed in Web Technologies. But this project is requiring me to use Web Technologies. So I was wondering if you could guide me a bit. Please see the edit above. I get the feeling that I am doing something wrong but bot quite sure where. Thanks again.

Comment: I just found out that the intended page is not getting loaded. I just found this Gist which seems relevant.https://gist.github.com/amaitland/40394439ddefdf4e66b7

Comment: The behaviour looks a bit strange. I initialize browser with a url and get the message that the page is loaded. Then I do a browser.Load() and get the previously loaded page which probably was not loaded at that point. Is there something special I need to do?

Comment: I tried the code in the above link but I couldn't find NavStateChangedEventArgs and browser.NavStateChanged.

Comment: I think there is a problem accessing the DOM because when I execute 2+2 I get 4 but when I try to access DOM I get nothing. Is there some setting I need to set?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the page loads. Also if the page loads data using ajax, you need to wait a bit to data also load. Then you need to shape the result to a custom javascript object.

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(
        "https://google.com/"); // Tried with your URL. 
    browser.LoadingStateChanged += Browser_LoadingStateChanged;
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Controls.Add(browser);
}

private async void Browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender,
    LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsLoading)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000); //Just for pages which use ajax loading data
        var script = @"
        (function () {
            var data = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            return Array.from(data, a => ({href:a.href, innerText:a.innerText}));
        })();";
        var result = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
        var data = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)result.Result;

        MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", data.Select(x=>$"{x.href}").Distinct()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add a bit more detail,  CEF supports returning arrays, the call to getElementsByTagName returns a HTMLCollection which is array like,  not strictly speaking an array, it's dynamically updated as the DOM changes. You cannot return a HTMLCollection directly, the HTMLCollection must be turned into an array as shown in this answer. For reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Comment: I'll also add that using a fixed length delay isn't necessarily the best option, using a MutationObserver in conjunction with calling CefSharp.PostMessage from within JavaScript can be used where a more precise timing is required.  For reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver and https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775